# Using Google Play in app purchases to implement a chargeable voting system

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I have an app in which I wish to implement a system where the user pays through an in-app purchase for every vote he/she casts. The user can cast votes as many times as he/she wishes to.

Now, Google Play in app purchase provides two types of in-app products -

1. Managed
2. Subscription

(Unmanaged Type falls under a deprecated API version so I cannot use it)

For my requirement, Subscription does not match at all.

Managed type too says - "Managed items that can be purchased only once per user account on Google Play". This limits the user to only one vote per contestant he/she is voting for.

Also, A managed purchase item is consumable but a vote cannot be.

Hence, I get a feeling that Google's in app purchase system is not meant for my kind of requirement. Is this true? Is there a way around?

Answer (score 0):

So, I mailed the Google Help Desk and they said that my requirements cannot be met via in-app purchase. So, it's a no go.